# How to show image with another url?

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

I have images like this:

```
/images/10.png
```

And i have array:

```
$arr = [10 => 'pretty_name'];
```

Is possible to display image 10.png but using pretty_name?

```
<img src="/images/pretty_name.png"/>
```

I tried return image with proper headers (Content-Type: image/png). It work but it is slow.

Can i do that with htaccess for example?

Comment: So you want to use /images/pretty_name.png to display /images/10.png? You would have to find the array key first (array_search), then img src to /images/pretty_name.png

Comment: Yes i want to do this but i need to display pretty name in DOM. 10.png cannot be visible in HTML.

Comment: Why do you want that? A name of an image to define and get it. If you change the name, it no longer is it. That's my idea.

Comment: You would have to abstract your images through some sort of processor script to achieve anything similar

Comment: We have pictures on 1 server. This pictures are used by 3 pages. I need to create pretty url's for this pictures. @scottevans93 firstly i think about .htaccess but i do not know if that is possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use .htaccess and something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?images/([0-9]+)/.*(\..*)$ /images/$1$2
```

Then in your HTML you can write your image URLs like this:

```
<img src="/images/10/pretty_name.png" />
```

The rewrite rule will parse out the filename (in this case, 10) as well as the extension (.png) and rewrite it to the real path, ignoring the "pretty_name" part entirely.

The downside is that *any* "pretty name" will work. For example, these would all point to /images/10.png:

```
/images/10/pretty_name.png
/images/10/something_random.png
/images/10/earth_photo.png
```

This is because there's no reverse check to make sure the pretty name matches the ID. Whether or not this is tolerable depends on your application.

Comment: Great idea. Thank you!